# STM32 SPI Clock will not idle high

Tags: stm32, spi

Using STM32F103RBT6 chip (Specifcally Olimex STM32- H103 Board), Keil u5. Communicating with AS5311 magnetic sensor

SPI peripheral is setup in master mode uni-directional rx only. CPHA = 1 and CPOL = 1. The clock pin is set as alternate function push pull. initialisation of SPI is below:

```
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_RXONLY;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLED;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLED;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1);
```

I then enter a loop with the following code simply on a constant receive mode

```
while (1)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)Rx_Buffer, 3, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(1);
}
```

I've checked the polarity and phase in the perihperhal viewer and can see the registers are set as 1 for both CPOL and CPHA. However when using a saleae logic analyser i can see that after transfer of data the clock does not idle high.
[image: SALEAE Capture of SPI data]

In terms of hardware the clock is directly connected with no pull up/down resistors.

Any ideas why the clock wont idle high?

Comment: Looks like it will idle at high when enabled.

Comment: @EugeneSh. when it comes out of the HAL_SPI_Recieve function, the SPI is disabled?

Comment: I am talking about the bottom signal which seem to make difference (not sure, though as not enough of it is shown)

Comment: @EugeneSh. the signals all continue as shown at the end of the traces i.e. clock low, Enable low and MISO low. until the delay finishes and a new recieve is enabled

Comment: What this signal is connected to (what is driving it)? Is this `GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes it is    GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1. So this will not affect the SPI clock at all

Comment: Who is the slave? Upd: Nevermind, I see it

Comment: Change to the first edge. O

Comment: Hmm, I think I had the same issue, the pin seems to go into high impedance mode after the peripheral finished the transaction. I enabled the pull-up on the pin. Maybe some further investigation will find a better fix, but I had to move on.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 the slave device requires second edge, but will change to see if it affects

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar issue and after days of research and debugging, I noticed a trend that everyone who was having this issue configured their SPI as RX only.  When I changed my SPI to TX RX mode the issue was magically solved.  I'm not sure what could cause this, but it seems like a bug on ST's end, either as part of the HAL library, or as part of the device itself.  Either way, now I just have an unused MOSI pin configured, but the SCK idle problem has been solved.  Hope this helps save someone some time and headache!

Answer (score 0):

Pin goes to floating state (high impedance, hi-Z) after N clock pulses. Issue solved by configuring clock pin to internal pull-up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to send (trasmit) dummy byte (without CS) right after configuring the SPI interface.